# Possible contradiction in VHDL Std 1076?

Tags: vhdl, bit, synthesis

The following two quoted portions of the IEEE 1076-2008 VHDL standard appear contradictory or at least confusing:

5.2.2.2 Scalar types, Enumeration types, Predefined enumeration types, Note 2:

> Type BOOLEAN can be used to model either active high or active low
>   logic depending on the particular conversion functions chosen to and
>   from type BIT.

16.8.2.4.2 Standard synthesis packages, Interpretation fo the standard logic types, Interpretation of logic values, Interpretation of the forcing and weak values ('0', '1', 'L', 'H', FALSE, TRUE), paragraphs 1 and 2:

> A synthesis tool shall interpret the following values as representing a logic value 0:
>   — The BIT value '0'
>   — The BOOLEAN value FALSE
>   — The STD_ULOGIC values '0' and 'L'
>
> It shall interpret the following values as representing a logic value 1:
>   — The BIT value '1'
>   — The BOOLEAN value TRUE
>   — The STD_ULOGIC value '1' and 'H'

If the synthesis tool is mandated to interpret *false* as a logic 0 and *true* as a logic 1, what is the role of the "particular conversion functions chosen to and from type BIT"?

Comment: You seem to be soliciting opinion by little context free snippets. I'll give another snippet as a bit of context, 16.8.2.1: "This subclause (16.8.2) defines how a synthesis tool shall interpret values of the standard logic types defined in IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164 and of the BIT and BOOLEAN types defined in STD.STANDARD. Simulation tools, however, shall continue to interpret these values according to the clauses of this standard in which the values are defined." A get out of jail card preventing the latter quoted snippet being held as black and white 'law' universally.

Comment: This question would be more palatable in the form of 'Why does this appear contradictory?' without the 'Am I the only one who finds this' bit. Questions encouraging opinions or inviting protracted discussion are discouraged on stackoverflow. The snarky-ness of the preceding comment (and it's predecessor) is intended to imply context is everything in VHDL, the 16.8.2.1 subclause comes from researching context for your question.

Comment: @DavidKoontz true, do you think I should further edit the question or was it the purpose of the edits already in place? Thanks for making the question more appropriate.

Comment: You have edit rights to your own question. Are there any points missing from it now, or something needing emphasis? The note is present in -1987.  16.8, -2008. My guess is that the note had to do with mixed ECL/TTL board level simulation in lieu of a new ECL type (and operators). Haven't found any papers showing such a use. This predates std_logic_1164. 16.8.2.1 should still be viewed as a barrier to connecting the two. I can remove my comments if it will help get you an answer.